# Why does it lead to a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

It just shows me: [1] 10531 Segmentation fault.
I don't what is the problem of my code!(I have defined a list and add an element into the list. But it just failed and I don't know how to change it.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ll {
    int val;
    struct ll *next;
} ll_t;

void copylist(ll_t* list, int* array, int length) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array[i] = list->val;
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    ll_t *list = NULL;
    int *array = NULL;
    list = malloc(sizeof (ll_t));
    list->val = 1;
    list->next = NULL;

    ll_t *add1 = NULL;
    add1 = malloc(sizeof (ll_t));
    add1->val = 2;
    add1->next = NULL;
    list->next = add1;
    int j;
    copylist(list, array, 2);
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        printf("the content of array is: %d\n", array[j]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `array` is not allocated.

Comment: Have you initialized *all* pointers? Are all pointers pointing to some valid memory of enough size?

Comment: Aside: you are using a linked list, but controlling it with the number of elements, instead of with the `NULL` value sentinel link intended for the purpose.

Comment: Although the array not being allocated is probably what's causing the issue, you should probably check that list is not null before trying to set `array[i] = list -> val`

Comment: i am sure that list is not null and  I don't really understand how can I fix this problem. Could you please help me to write the most important steps of my code?

Comment: Parse a linked list like this: `while(list != NULL && i < length) { array[i++] = list->val; list = list->next; }`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have tried with array=(int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int)); But still the problem.

Comment: Tried where? If done in the right place it should work.

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried, but not the problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have added the "array=(int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));" in the funktion of copylist and in front of for().

Comment: So no, you should do it in `main`.

Comment: But it a task for us and we can't change or add anything in main(). Is there other ways that I can copy the value of the list to array?

Comment: @Yun you **need** to modify _main_ because even the array is allocated in _copylist_  that will have no impact in _main_ (the call is not `copylist(list, &array, 2);` for instance)

Comment: @bruno thank you, i wil ask our teacher.

Answer (score 2):

Currently all that you're passing as an array is a null pointer because you instantiate it as

```
int *array = NULL;
```

instead of

```
int *array = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

which allocates enough space for two integers on the heap. (two being the amount of items you're using in this test).

Also, You should use

```
int i = 0;
while(list != NULL) {

    array[i] = list->val;
    list = list->next;
    i++;
}
```

instead of passing the length value, as you know when you reach the end of a linked list when you reach a null value. If someone were to input the wrong length by accident in your program it would lead to another segmentation fault.

Comment: I have added the malloc for array in the funktion of copylist but still dosen't work. have I putted it in a wrong place?for our Task we can not change anything in the main().

Comment: now I know the malloc in main is OK but I can only write the code in funktion copy.

Comment: The way main is written could not work without being edited, array starts off as null and then is attempted to be indexed at the end of the program which is undefined behavior and likely a guaranteed segmentation fault. If this is an assignment you should ask your teacher why it's left null, it seems like a mistake on their end.

Comment: thank you. I will ask my teacher.